# Adding shell interpreter to zeppelin

Tags: shell, interpreter, apache-zeppelin

I am using zeppelin 0.6.1-SNAPSHOT bundled with another in-memory computing platform called insightedge. I want to import other notebooks to my zeppelin deployment which require the shell interpreter (%sh).

I tried adding the shell interpreter by executing the `./install-interpreter.sh --name shell` command but that failed with error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find interpreter 'shell'
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.install(InstallInterpreter.java:141)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.install(InstallInterpreter.java:128)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.install.InstallInterpreter.main(InstallInterpreter.java:280)
```

The interpreter currently installed on my zeppelin installation are %spark & %md.

Kindly guide me through the steps to add the shell interpreter to my zeppelin deployment. Thanks.

Comment: is install a fresh Zeppelin an option? and try to `./install-interpreter.sh -l` to list if there is shell interpreter.

Comment: Since zeppelin came bundled along with another technology solution, fresh install is not an option. I checked the currently installed interpreters and just found %spark & %md.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to install the shell interpreter on my zeppelin deployment by executing the command

```
"./install-interpreter.sh --name shell --artifact org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-shell:0.6.1"
```

Answer (score 2):

If

```
"./install-interpreter.sh --name shell --artifact org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-shell:0.8.0"
```

didn't help you should try add **zeppelin-shell-0.8.0.jar** artifact dependency to shell interpreter:
[image]